# What is the probability that the number of red balls will always be bigger than number of blue balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a box, there are $n$ red balls and $m$ blue balls where $n>m$. We pick a ball one by one until the box is empty. What is the probability that at every moment, out of the box, the number of red balls is greater than the number of blue balls?

My textbook has given only a solution $\dfrac{n-m}{n+m}$ but no derivation. And I can't get to the right answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: You're more likely to receive help if you also include your own thought and working in the post. That would help us identify _where_ you went wrong.

Comment: Brother I've been staring at this problem for 5 hours and all I have is drawings of binary trees where I count the results, thanks for the wiki link tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try small examples.  If $m=0$ then it is guaranteed.  If $n=2, m=1$, then the only way to succeed is $RRB$ because we want strictly greater.  So the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$.

If $n=3, m=1$ then $RRBR$ and $RRRB$ both work, so the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.
If $n=3, m=2$ then $RRBRB$, $RRRBB$ are the only two that work.  There are $10$ ways to arrange $2B$'s among $3R$'s (${5 \choose 2} = 10)$.

Considering all cases doesn't seem to be making an obvious pattern yet.  Another approach is to fix one variable, say $m=1$, and let $n$ vary and find that general case.  That one is simple enough, because so long as the first two are red, success is guaranteed.  So the probability of that is $$\frac{{n \choose 2}}{n+m \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)n} = \frac{n-1}{n+1}$$ which matches your general solution.

Now consider $m=2$. We must start with $2R$'s. We can then follow with anything but $2B$'s. $$P(RRBB|RR) = \frac{m \choose 2}{n+m-2 \choose 2} = \frac{2 \choose 2}{n \choose 2} = \frac{2}{n(n-1)}$$ so we get $$\frac{{n \choose 2}}{n+2 \choose 2} \cdot \big(1-\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\big) = \frac{n(n-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}\cdot \big(1-\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\big)$$ or $$\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}\cdot \frac{(n-2)(n+1)}{n(n-1)} = \frac{n-2}{n+2}$$ as expected.

The general case is harder, but that gives you a procedure to try to generalize.